# Admin generate layout (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I make a Rails App, where admin can generate the homepage of the App (item positions, adding new items, deleting others, etc). I know that I have to store it in DB. But I am not really sure what I am supposed to store in the table.
So, in Admin page I want to make the edit homepage with drop and drag menu. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: well your question is quite vague, can you be more specific, provide some examples of your code and what your doing... as for drag and drop look at jquery

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't specify my question. I will try the answer from Vikram first, but thank you for your time, Richlewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is it depends - If you are providing the admin an interface to edit home page with drag and drop or delete specific content, then you should store html contents of that page in DB and if you are giving only reference to edit then you should store those references only. But i will go for storing html contents. And again it completely depends on your requirement and you are the best person to understand and implement that.

Comment: I am providing an interface in admin page to edit the layout. So it's better to store the html content. Thank you vikram :-)